# Custom form Validation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am wondering if i have set up my method incorrectly as my validation attempt is being ignored halfway through the method. (i have provided a basic example, i want to get this working before adding more)

I have two variations of a form all belonging to the same object. The forms are differentiated by a column animal_type as you can see in my method

```
 class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save :animal_form_validation


  private
  def animal_form_validation
    if self.animal_type == 'Dog'
      ap('Im validating the dog Form')
        if self.name.length <= 0
          errors.add(:name, "Name cannot be blank")
        end
    elsif self.animal_type == 'Cat'
      ap('Im validating the cat form')
        if self.name.length <= 0
          errors.add(:name, "Name cannot be blank")
        end
    end
  end
end
```

whether i am submitting a cat or dog i get the correct message in the console (using awesome print), so the method is running and knows which form im submitting, but as for the next if statement it is being ignored.

So i have an error with my syntax? or am i calling the wrong validation check on the name field ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume your actual validation is more complex, and that's why you're not just using `validates_presence_of :name`?

Comment: yes, of course :-) im testing my validation with one field before moving onto the rest

Comment: The `self.name.length <= 0` test looks odd to me for some reason. Does it work if you try `self.name.blank?` ?

Comment: that doesn't work either I'm afraid

Comment: with there going to be a lot of fields validated, would a case statement be better here?

Comment: @Richlewis Doing validations in a `before_save` callback is a little odd to me. You can write your own [custom validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations). Otherwise, try removing the `self` and use `name.blank?`. Any reason why you're using a callback instead of a custom validation?

Comment: what value is getting printed for self.name

Comment: @mmichael I must have got confused, i thought I had to run my custom validation with a before_save, reading the docs properly has cleared that up it seems, validate :animal_form_validation works now, thank you

Comment: also, do i really need self as im already in the class so have access to the params dont I?

Comment: Correct, you don't need `self` if you're validating attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use validation instead of a `before_save` callback:

`validate :animal_form_validation`

Also, you can add [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) if you're checking the same condition prior to validating. Example: `validate :animal_form_validation, if: name.blank?`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling those validation in `before_save`, which is after the record has been validated and is assumed to be valid. You need to run it as a validation:

```
validate :animal_form_validation
```